# WPF MVVM Community Toolkit and Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, toolkit

In a project C# WPF I started using the MVVM Community Toolkit and my question is about properties. Let's say I have a Model with some properties:

```
public class TheModel
{
public bool FirstProp {get; set;}
public int SecondProp {get; set;}
}
```

Then I have a Viewmodel with instance of that Model, usually I set properties like this:

```
public class TheViewModel : ObservableObject
{
private readonly TheModel _theModel;

public bool FirstProp
{
    get => _theModel.FirstProp;
    set
    {
        if (_theModel.FirstProp != value)
        {
            _theModel.FirstProp = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public int SecondProp
{
    get => _theModel.SecondProp;
    set
    {
        if (_theModel.SecondProp != value)
        {
            _theModel.SecondProp = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public TheViewModel(TheModel theModel)
{
_theModel = theModel;
}

}
```

My question: I wonder if there is a shorter way provided by MVVM Community toolkit to set properties (such as FirstProp and SecondProp) in the view model

The above code is working but if you have many properties it becomes boring to write them all

Comment: I would copy the property values from a model instance to a viewmodel instance using mapping software such as Mapperly or Automapper. That way you write little code. Such mappers also offer the benefit of deep clone.

Comment: thank you, to be honest i never used them so I am going to take a look as it seems interesting, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SetProperty method:

```cs
public bool FirstProp
{
    get => _theModel.FirstProp;
    set => SetProperty(_theModel.FirstProp, value, _theModel, (m, v) => m.FirstProp = v);
}
```

It makes the value check for you and calls OnPropertyChanged.
Whether it's less code that the other I leave up to you.

Comment: thanks for answer. When I try your suggestion, I get an error. I have error: CS0206 - A non ref-returning property or indexer may not be used as an out or ref value. What can be the reason of this error?

Comment: I've changed the answer to something found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject) under *Wrapping a non-observable model*

Comment: ok so when you try to pass _theModel.FirstProp as a parameter to the SetProperty method, you are trying to pass a property as a reference parameter, which is not allowed in C#. Reference parameters must be variables, not properties. This is correct?

Comment: That's correct, but see my edited answer.

Comment: Ok I am going to try the edited version, thank you